# How do I get the compressed file sizes in a directory and all its subdirectories?

Tags: python, directory, compression, filesize

I'm trying to find the compressed sizes(i.e., gzip) of all the files in a directory and all its sub-directories. Previously, I had successfully extracted all the file sizes but I don't know how to find the compressed file sizes without actually compressing the files. Here's my original code:

```
import os
path = os.getcwd()
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for file in filenames:
        file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
        file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
        print("{} : {}".format(file_path, round(file_size, 3)))
    for dirname in dirnames:
        dir_path = os.path.join(dirpath, dirname)
        dir_size = os.path.getsize(dir_path)
        print("{} : {}".format(dir_path, round(dir_size, 3)))
```

I want to get the gzip(compressed) file sizes in the same line as the name of the file. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You mean the files are not currently compressed, but you want to predict what the size would be once compressed?  This is not possible without actually compressing them.

Comment: Yes it's impossible to get the size of a compressed data before compressing them. Are you asking how to compress on the memory?